# How to run Flyway commands in spring boot application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, flyway

I've been using flyway to handle my sql scripts migrations and am very happy with it. However, when I decided to move forward with spring boot and flyway I have stuck when I tried to run the different flyway commands from the app.

When I run my fat jar app, the `migrate` flyway command is automatically executed. All went well until one of the scripts failed in a linux (because of the case sensitive). So, when I wanted to execute the `repair` command I had no way to do it, so I had to manually remove the entry in the `schema_version` table.

So, my question is that if it is even possible to other flyway commands through the app without creating a custom flyway handler and just using its native integration.

I didn't find any spring boot property for `command` or something like this.

Any help?

Comment: You can always use `flyway-maven-plugin`.

Comment: @AliDehghani keep in mind that I meant about the fat jar app in our test server and not the source code

Answer (score 3):

There's no `command` property for Flyway integration. If you want you can implement your own `FlywayMigrationStrategy`, which is a one method interface:

```
public interface FlywayMigrationStrategy {

    /**
     * Trigger flyway migration.
     * @param flyway the flyway instance
     */
    void migrate(Flyway flyway);

}
```

You can pick up for instance a command line argument that you pass and do `repair` instead of `migrate`:

```
void migrate(Flyway flyway) {
    String command = env.getProperty("flyway.commamd", "migrate");
    switch (command) {
     case "migrate":
         flyway.migrate();
         break;
     case "repair":
         flyway.repair();
         break;
     default:
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid command: " + command);
 }
}
```

Check the docs [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-execute-flyway-database-migrations-on-startup).